# prevent cycle from returning to first slide on submit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, cycle

i have a cycle with pager in a custom made plugin on wordpress the problem is

i have page with 2 tabs

first one is waiting users
second is accepted users and there is a search filter in this tab

```
 <ul id="pager">
     <li><h2><a href="#">Pending Requests</a></h2></li>
     <li><h2><a href="#">Approved & Filter</a></h2></li>
 </ul>
```

when i fill the search and click submit it takes me back to first slider how can i make it return to the same tab (which is the second tab) after submit

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul id="pager">
     <li id="pendingrequests"><h2><a href="#">Pending Requests</a></h2></li>
     <li id="approvedfilter"><h2><a href="#">Approved & Filter</a></h2></li>
 </ul>
```

please change the post or get action url to current_URL#approvedfilter

Comment: i guess the only way to do this is to pass a parameter to the url using jquery and then put the parameter in the action of form